# Ternary operator type selection in case of private inheritance between argument types in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, conditional-operator

The type of C++ conditional (ternary) operator `E1 ? E2 : E3` in case of distinct types `E2` and `E3` is selected as one of them if the other operand can be uniquely converted to that type. The set of rules is actually more complex and summarized in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator

In the following simplified program, the operands of the conditional operator are rvalues of types `A` and `B`:

```
class A;
struct B {
    B() {}
    B(const A &) {}
};
class A : B {};

int main() {
    void( true ? B{} : A{} );
}
```

Since `A` is derived privately from `B`, no cast to parent is possible, but `A` can be uniquely converted to `B` using the constructor `B::B(const A &)`. And no cast from `B` to `A` is available. So I would expect that the type of the ternary operator be `B` with the last argument converted in that type. And indeed, Clang accepts the program.

But GCC prints an error here:

```
error: 'B' is an inaccessible base of 'A'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n56vf4qzY

Which of the compilers is right here?

Comment: All three accept `void( true ? B{} : B{A{}} );`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not what I would expect really, where is my thinking taking a wrong turn?

Comment: @PKramer `B::B(const A&)` is public so `B` has no problem with `B{A{}}`.

Comment: All three also lets this through: `static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<A, B>);`

Comment: Ok the B{A{}} made me see it, thanks!

Comment: not sure if it applies, but i stumbled upon [4.3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#4.3.2): "[...] otherwise, if T2 is a base class of T1, the target type is cv1 T2, where cv1 denotes the cv-qualifiers of T1," I find it confusing that it only says "T2 is a base class of T1" rather than "T2 is an accesible base class of T1".

Comment: Note [Note 2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#note-2), regarding the determination of an implicit conversion: "Properties such as access, whether an operand is a bit-field, or whether a conversion function is deleted are ignored for that determination.
— end note". This suggests to me that gcc *might* be right here, but this section could do with some clarification. (This reminds me of how implicit conversion is Evil and that everything is Algol's fault.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73922073/481267